# Strange currency on websites Argentina

Tags: money, local-customs, price, argentina

I checked prices on some sites and have feeling of strong misunderstanding: according to Wikw the currency os peso, but prices are in '$'. Moreover, the price seems to be unreasonably high, please see screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

From my standpoint, almost USD 12k is weird (you can buy used big 4WD in Europe within 2K or less), so I believe I just misunderstand something.

Could you please explain how much it really costs (in USD or EUR) and why such a way to display prices?

p.s. tried to compare how it'll be cheaper to travel across SA: by public transport or buy something like that.

Comment: Could it be that 11890.00 in pesos is roughly $658.68 US Dollars or roughly 589 euro?

Comment: Maybe, but the dollar signs?

Comment: $ = dollar, and thereby money in general, not just USD. Have you checked other Argentinan sites, whether they do use that same sign and whether the prices are comparible?

Comment: @Putnik that is common across a lot of poorly designed web sites...I've seen it a lot.  If for instance, you still question it you can contact the owners of the item / someone who does know within the site.

Comment: @Willeke the dollar sign originates with the peso (as does the dollar itself, which was originally the "Spanish dollar").  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign#Origin.  It is similar to Italy formerly using £ for lira.

Comment: @JonH it's not poor design. Many countries use the so-called dollar sign for their currencies.

Comment: @phoog okay fair enough but that price is in pesos.

Comment: @JonH and nothing on the site indicates that the price is in anything other than pesos.  The sign for the Argentine peso is *$*.

Comment: @phoog - right exactly waht I am telling op.

Comment: @pnuts I tried to compare how it'll be cheaper to travel across SA: by public transport or buy something like that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The dollar sign derives from an abbreviation for the Spanish-American peso, the currency from which the US dollar itself derives.  Many countries use this sign for their currencies.  Any use of the sign without further specifying the currency is therefore ambiguous, which is why [ISO currency codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) exist.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar.

Argentina is among the many countries using this sign for their currency.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentine_peso:

> The peso (originally established as the peso convertible) is the currency of Argentina, identified by the symbol $ preceding the amount in the same way as many countries using dollar currencies.

Comment: Also, while the Brazilian real and Peruvian sol technically use different symbols, their symbols are very similar to the dollar sign, and are often indistinguishable when handwritten.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find that higher-value items (e.g. real estate) are priced in US dollars in Argentina. These will be marked as US$ as the dollar sign on its own means Argentine Pesos (currency code ARS).

Comment: I think this should be converted to a comment.